# In Sitecore 10, why would my Content Editor Panel not open

Tags: sitecore

I using Sitecore 10, I clicked on Content Editor and the folder in my content tree are there and available, but I cannot display the Panel to edit an item in the Content Tree.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most likely explanation is that your Sitecore instance sends an empty response to the "/sitecore/shell/Applications/Content%20Editor.aspx" request: meaning that the response has an empty body.

This event is usually accompanied by an error in the logs containing "at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager". Please look for similar errors and share the full stack trace here.

Errors like this can help identify misconfiguration or third-party modules that interfere with base Sitecore functionality.